# Powering on my esata external disk makes windows freeze for 15-30 seconds

Tags: windows-vista, freeze, esata

I have a SATA disk in an external eSATA enclosure.  Most of the time it's powered off, but when I turn it on windows hangs for 15-30 seconds.  No sound, no mouse, nothing.  Then after 15-30 seconds, everything is fine again.

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

The enclosure is a Vantec Nexstar 3, and the disks have both been Western Digitals.  (I only have the two to play with.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try new driver for eSATA controller or for chipset.

Comment: I installed my motherboard (intel) raid-drivers and it seemed to help for this problem, very strange

Comment: Updating chipset (and raid) drivers has fixed it.